# Expresso Store - remember form fields if inline error

Tags: expresso-store

I wish to pre-populate my billing and shipping details for logged in members

VALUE="{exp:member:custom_profile_data}{firstName}{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}"

This correctly populates the form fields however when I submit the form when there is an error on the form such as a required field not being complete all the form fields are reset to blank.

So I basically need something along the lines of the following:

if inline error then use

```
VALUE="{firstName}"
```

otherwise use the following:

```
VALUE="{exp:member:custom_profile_data}{firstName}{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}"
```

Is this possible? If so anyone care to share the syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you map the form fields by going to Store > Settings > Order Fields and map each of the order fields to your respected member profile fields as seen in the screenshot:
[image: Order Fields]

You can then use:

```
{field:first_name}
```

or

```
{field:billing_state}
```

to have the value populated automatically on return visits for that member but also will persist through page loads.

**EDIT:**

As Adrian mention in the comments you need to empty your cart anytime you make changes to your member data as it is only loaded once.

Comment: Note that you need to empty your cart between each test for this to work. The mapped member fields are only loaded once per cart.

Comment: Great point, I have edited the answer to include that.